# Syntax error in math.randomseed( os.time() )

Tags: lua, syntax-error

I am creating some code for a scripted weapon in LUA, and I wan't a random of 3 explosion sounds. It doesn't seem to work, and I get this error-

```
    syntax error near unexpected token 'os.time'
```

This is a snippet of the script that seems to be where the error is coming from-

```
    math.randomseed( os.time() )
    local expthink = math.random(3,5)
    if expthink == 3 then local explosionsound = "explode3.wav"
    elseif expthink == 4  then local explosionsound = "explode4.wav"
    elseif expthink == 5 then local explosionsound = "explode5.wav"
    end
```

Also I am running my test.lua file in Git Bash so I can see the output, does that effect anything?

This is the output I get in command prompt:

[Click to see Image](http://s33.postimg.org/fd46y5edb/Capture.jpg)

(Not enough reputation to post images)

Comment: It's likely there's a problem *before* the first line you showed.  When I copy-and-paste your snippet into a `tmp.lua` file, `lua tmp.lua` reports no syntax errors.

Comment: Keith Thompson, I put that code into a seperate LUA file, ran it, and it showed the same error, so I don't think it is the code in it's entirety's fault. I downloaded lua from the official website as well. I am running it in lua.exe but should I run it in luac.exe?

Comment: I don't know. I can just tell you that I don't get the same error. (I'm on LInux, not Windows, using Lua 5.2.3 and 5.3.2.) Neither `lua` nor `luac` gives me an error.

Comment: Using latest version, Windows. Specs- Windows 10, Intel Pentium CPU 2127U @ 1.90GHz 1.90 GHz Processor, 64 bit OS and x64 based processor, Touch Support. Is it because I have an x64?

Comment: @KeithThompson Weird. When I run it in command prompt (instead of git bash) after adding "print(explosionsound)" at the end, I get the response nil. It works, but its not what I want, it should print "explode3.wav", "explode4.wav", or "explode5.wav"

Comment: Also see the image linked in the description there /\

Comment: You defined `explosionsound` as `local`. That means you have three different `explosionsound` variables, each local to the block in which it appears. Declare it outside the `if`. (But that's not relevant to the original question about the syntax error.) BTW, images even inline images, are fare less useful than copy-and-pasted text.

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token` is not Lua error message, it is message from Bash.  It seems that you are trying to run Lua file as bash script.  Do you use proper shebang?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KeithThompson for this answer.

Simply don't define the explosionsound variable as local.

```
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    local expthink = math.random(3,5)
    if expthink == 3 then explosionsound = "explode3.wav"
    elseif expthink == 4  then explosionsound = "explode4.wav"
    elseif expthink == 5 then explosionsound = "explode5.wav"
    end
    print(explosionsound)
```

Thanks to @EgorSkriptunoff for this edit-
EDIT: Also, running it in Bash is not a good idea. Bash is not compatible with lua files like it is with batch files. It runs it as a bash script, and it does not see
        math.randomseed( os.time() )
as correct syntax.

Comment: I don't see how that would address the syntax error which is what you originally asked about.

Comment: I agree with Keith, making `explosionsound` local to a branch of the if-block has little to do with syntax errors. If your code works now, probably something else was changed. Also, if `explosionsound` isn't declared as local somewhere else, then it lives in the global environment `_G` and you'll probably find some mysterious bugs later.

Comment: Hmm... I agree, and earlier in the first post running the lua file in the command prompt after adding return explosionsound at the end gives me nil, not because of the randomseed, which I claimed to be causing syntax errors, but the local part. (I'm on an iOS at the moment so putting code blocks is a hassle.)